# When does the .net garbage collector do for long running method?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, clr

If I have method which is doing a long job (making a web service call for example), does the Garbage collector look at the memory used by the method and move it through the different generations or does it ignore the method until it has finished and then try to collect the memory at a later data?

I heard an explanation where if a web service call is being made, the GC would look at it and since it was taking a long time, mark it a generation 1, then generation 2. Now we could have a bulk of memory that won't be collected until at a later stage. Is this correct?

Comment: GC does nothing in terms of methods. MSDN provides a lot of description for GC work flow - [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee787088(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: So the explanation about moving to generation 2 is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When GC starts it looks at object roots. It does not care whether those roots are from method variables or instance/static fields. It would not release resources that are referenced from the method because those references are alive until method is exited.

Comment: If it's not running in debug mode, resources referenced by the method *may* be cleaned up as soon as the method no longer uses the reference, even if the method is still running.

Comment: "It would not release resources that are referenced from the method because those references are alive until method is exited". That is not true in general.

Answer (score 0):

Methods are not directly visible to the GC, i.e. it is oblivious to them.

Answer (score -1):

Garbage collector doesn't look for methods. GC checks for references.

Simple example: if you define a global variable, it can be accessed from every function of the scope. It will be NOT collected, until you leave the scope.
If you define a local variable, let's say inside of the function, the memory used by this variable will be cleared after the function's return (or `finally` block in case you returned from try/catch block)

Comment: "will be cleared after the function's return" - I'd add some weasel words about "some time after" there - how quickly it happens depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, better say after return and next time GC is executed.